# Thread.sleep called in loop - how to prevent it in this case (by refactoring)?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, jsoup

I'm facing the following warning in NetBeans:

[image: warning]

I know this is a common issue people face and I read some related questions before posting. But in this specific case - where I'm doing an [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) to download a document using Jsoup - I'm not sure how to prevent the warning.
I thought about a timer with increasing time, but... is it the most elegant way?

```
Document downloadPageAsDocument(String url) throws IOException {
    long waitTime = MILLIS_PER_SECOND;
    while (waitTime < MILLIS_PER_HOUR) {
        try {
            return Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(REQ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS).get(); // an IOException is thrown on timeout by Jsoup
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "{0}... wating {1} seconds", new Object[]{ex.getMessage(), (waitTime / MILLIS_PER_SECOND)});
            try {
                Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex1) {
            }
            waitTime *= 2;
        }
    }
    throw new IOException("I quited after " + (waitTime / MILLIS_PER_SECOND) + " seconds");
}
```

Comment: A timer is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a `Thread.sleep()` is rarely a good solution, I think your case is an exception, because it makes your intention clear. So, I'd take @user1274820 advice to add a `@SuppressWarnings`. However, here is how I would do this without using `Thread.sleep()`

```
static ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

Document downloadPageAsDocument(String url) throws IOException {
    AtomicLong waitTime = new AtomicLong(MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
    try {
        while (waitTime.get() < MILLIS_PER_HOUR) {
            System.out.println("iteration wait=" + waitTime.get());
            ScheduledFuture<String> future = exec.schedule(() -> {
                try {
                    return jsoupCall();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    waitTime.getAndUpdate((l) -> l * 2);
                }
                return null;
            }, waitTime.get(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (future.get() != null) { // wait for completion
                break; //break if jsoupCall was successful
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // handle exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: seems good! but is this not an active wait? I mean: `if (future.get() != null)`: while call is not completed, it keeps cycling. Right? Seems to be resource consuming if it keeps cycling till it's true.

Comment: @LuísSoares No, `future.get()` is a blocking call. It will pause the current thread until the callable is finished.

Comment: great! I'll test later and accept the answer then.
BTW, why AtomicLong?

Comment: @LuísSoares because you are reading it from 2 threads: the main one and scheduled executor, so it needs to be synchronized.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it reads like programmers trying to push people into using the await/notify methods or TaskScheduling and some of the newer methods.

That being said, you can ignore the warning like this:

(I'm not sure which, but I believe it's one/both of these)

```
@SuppressWarnings("SleepWhileHoldingLock")
@SuppressWarnings("CallToNativeMethodWhileLocked")
```

http://hg.netbeans.org/jet-main/rev/1625627adda6

Thread I found this link from:

http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/69cat-editor-New-hint-Thread-sleep-called-in-loop-td3006136.html

Comment: thx. That would hide the warning... But I still believe a refactor is possible.

Answer (score 0):

How about recursive method calling !!

```
   Document downloadPageAsDocument(String url) throws IOException {
long waitTime = MILLIS_PER_SECOND;
if (waitTime < MILLIS_PER_HOUR) {
    try {
        return Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(REQ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS).get(); // an IOException is thrown on timeout by Jsoup
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "{0}... wating {1} seconds", new Object[]{ex.getMessage(), (waitTime / MILLIS_PER_SECOND)});
        try {
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
        waitTime *= 2;
        downloadPageAsDocument(url);
        } 
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {

       }
       catch(StackOverFlowError sfe)
       {
            sfe.printStackTrace();
        }
      catch (InterruptedException ex1) {
        }

    }
}
throw new IOException("I quited after " + (waitTime / MILLIS_PER_SECOND) + " seconds");
}
```

Comment: This could cause a StackOverflowError, after too many recursive calls

Comment: Then will catch `StackOverFlowError` evertime it reaches this error it will clears the stack and the loop wil back to normal.